# iOS Fonts and (Alleged) Extra Leading

Tags: ios, uikit, uifont, css

A recent project has called for the use of two Hiragino fonts on iOS 4.x (HiraKakuProN-W3 and -W6) ... but they appear to have some extra space (at least below the characters A-Za-z0-9, which is what I would end up using them for). That leads to all the text skewing a bit high.

For instance, in a UINavigationBar's custom title view, or in the text or detail label of a UITableViewCell, there's extra space below the text, and so it doesn't "line up" with everything else as you'd normally expect.

Perhaps this is as-designed, and is a misuse of the Hiragino font. If it isn't, however, is there something else I should be doing so that the font aligns vertically with little muss/fuss? It's not clear how to use these other fonts effectively in common situations ... unless I have no choice but to stick with tried and true system fonts. (But then why offer the fonts in the first place ... !)

FWIW, I also tried a few licensed-for-our-use fonts, Gotham Rounded Book and Gotham Rounded Bold. Same problem.

Comment: I've the same [problem][1]. I would like to know how you tackled it. Thanks!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943354/ios-japanese-characters-centering-issue

Comment: See my answer from March 6th - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news: Kevin Ballard's [FontLabel](https://github.com/kballard/FontLabel) appears to tame just about any font I throw at it. Thanks, Kevin! Will study the classes in more detail, but on the surface it looks like a winner.

Comment: FontLabel is massive overkill now, since iOS 4 does all of that. However, what FontLabel does do for you is actually use the font metrics. The standard UILabel does not honor the leading in the font, and appears to add a few extra pixels. Very frustrating.

Comment: Leading - hmm, frustrating indeed. I hear you WRT FontLabel being overkill with iOS 4. Later on, I went and compared our licensed Helvetica Neue font with one that was already on my Mac (using a font editor). Wouldn't you know it, the Mac version was vertically centered, while the Adobe one wasn't! Sigh.