# iOS japanese characters centering issue

Tags: ios, unicode, ios4, localization

For labels or for button titles, when i use helvetica font, it looks like this:
[image]

But when i use HiraKakuProN-W6(Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN W6)font(for japanese characters) it gives me this:[image]

I would like to know whether this is normal behaviour. If yes, I would be grateful to anyone who can tell me how to center the japanese font characters.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a problem. I'd recommend you to use System font.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered exactly the same problem, and find a way to solve it in iOS 6:

```
label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Start" attributes:@{
                                                                            NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HiraKakuProN-W6" size:16],
                                                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
                                                }];
```

p.s. for UIButton's titleLabel, setting a `NSAttributedText` into the `button.titleLabel` directly will not work, there is a method `- (void)setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);` available for `UIButton`.

Comment: Will check it and let u know :)